# Detecting plane surfaces in 3D model

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, mesh

I did a fast research on this topic and found nothing relevant so im asking here.
I have a 3D model in form of mesh(trianguled) from Kinect or some other 3D scanner.
What i want to do is identify homogenous plane surface such as doors,floor,tables etc in any given model

Do you know any algorithms to achieve it ? or what should i look for ?
thx in advance

Comment: IIRC where all partial derivatives of the second order (`d^2z/d^2x`, `d^2z/d^2y`) are zero, the surface is a plane. Someone better at maths, please confirm (or correct) me.

Comment: Hough transform (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to look for is groups of connected facets whose normal vectors are oriented in the same direction (within some margin of error).

Connected facets are easy enough to find — they are the ones that share edges in common.

You can obtain their normal vectors by calculating the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of two edges, being sure to choose these edges in a consistent way (e.g., by travelling clockwise around the outside of the facet). The size of the cross product is a function of the facet's area, but can be normalized to unit length to make comparisons simpler.

Comment: thanks a lot. Is this problem also connected with Hough transform mentioned above ?

Comment: No, the Hough transform is used to identify features (typically straight lines or circles) in 2D images. It doesn't work on 3D data.